# Probability of n events out of N that choose the same object

Tags: probability, combinations

I have to calculate the probability of `n` people out of `N` that choose the exact same object, among `k` objects. I am trying to figure out if this could be a modified version of the Birthday problem, or if it is a Bernoulli process.

What I have at the moment is the following:

$P = 1 - \frac{k!}{k^n(k-n)!}$

Since the first people will choose an object with probability $\frac{k}{k} = 1$, the second person not to choose the same number will have $\frac{k-1}{k}$ and so on. So, if I do 1 - this probability, I should get my answer.

I am not sure whether this is right or not. Does somebody have an idea about this?

Comment: If everyone has made a choice then $n_{i}$ of the $N$ persons will
have chosen for object $i$. This with $n_{1}+\cdots+n_{k}=N$. Can
you say what condition must be satisfied in terms of the $n_{i}$?
Do you want to find the probability that $n\in\left\{ n_{1},\dots,n_{k}\right\} $?

Comment: I want to find the probability that $k$ persons choose $i$.

Comment: In your question you speak of $n$ persons, not $k$.

Comment: Sorry, I want $n$ person, not $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a Binomial probability problem. Ignore the first person for the moment. Each person after them picks an object independently, and you want exactly $n - 1$ of them to pick *a particular* object (the same one the first person picked). The probability of any one person doing that is just $\frac{1}{k}$. There's a total of $N - 1$ people (attempts), and $N - 1 - (n - 1) = N - n$, so we get:

$$P = {N-1 \choose n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k} \right)^{n-1} \left(\frac{k - 1}{k}\right)^{N - n} $$

Then we need to consider the first person again. I've assumed they are literally the first person to choose, when they could be any of the $N$ people. So, we need to multiply the above by $N$.

**nb.** All of this assumes that it doesn't matter what all of the other $N - n$ people pick, so long as it's different from the 'first' choice. I don't know exactly what would need to change if you need the $N - n$ people to choose different objects to *each other* as well.